# Magento 2.3.4 salable quantity and default stock problem with one product

Tags: default, stock, magento-2.3, product-quantity

My version of Magento is 2.3.4
One of my product shows default value stock = 15, when true stock is 0.
I have checked the database and it's look like this.

```
mysql> select * from inventory_reservation;

| reservation_id | stock_id | sku          | quantity | metadata                                                                  |
+----------------+----------+--------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|             19 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"19"}      |
|             20 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"20"}      |
|             54 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"53"}      |
|             56 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"54"}      |
|             58 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"55"}      |
|             80 |        1 | HPR00005     |  -1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"66"}      |
|            127 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"1"}     |
|            128 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"2"}     |
|            129 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"3"}     |
|            130 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"4"}     |
|            131 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"5"}     |
|            132 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"6"}     |
|            133 |        1 | HPR00005     |   2.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"7"}     |
|            134 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"8"}     |
|            135 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"9"}     |
|            136 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"10"}    |
|            137 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"11"}    |
|            138 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"12"}    |
|            139 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"13"}    |
|            140 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"14"}    |
|            145 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"19"}    |
|            146 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"20"}    |
|            207 |        1 | HPR00005     |   1.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"66"}    |
|            283 |        1 | HPR00005     | -15.0000 | {"event_type":"order_placed","object_type":"order","object_id":"111"}     |
|            284 |        1 | HPR00005     |  15.0000 | {"event_type":"order_canceled","object_type":"order","object_id":"111"}   |
```

What can I see is there more canceled orders than placed. What can I see is there more canceled orders than placed.  Can we delete these reservation ?